# CefSharp Build issues in C#

Tags: c#

I've built a C# Windows Form Application which I have published but when I run it on my client's computer I receive this error ***'Could not load file or assembly 'CefSharp.Wpf, Version=41.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=40c4b6fc221f4138' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the specified file.'*** I am unsure on where to go from here in order to resolve this issue. I have checked that I am running the correct version (64bit) as I found that it is something to do with this. Any help would be really appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: Did you download and use the WinForms version of CefSharp? Are you using any other custom controls/libraries in your WinForms project that depend on WPF?

Comment: Yes, I downloaded CefSharp.WinForms from the NuGet installer.

Comment: Sorry, and I am not using any additional resources that WPF is dependent on.

Comment: You are using version 41 while the current seems to be 79. I suggest upgrading. Anyway some package depends on the WPF CefSharp. It might work for you because you at one point installed the WPF version in your GAC, while your client did not. You could try removing CefSharp temporarily and test if it works on client's PC.

Comment: https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Frequently-asked-questions#Runtime_dependencies